# Drawing recursive circles PYTHON

Tags: python, recursion

I can't get to draw the other smaller circles. Using recursive circles it's confusing me. How can I draw the rest of the circles? I called recursively the function draw_fractal_circles but it only draws one more smaller round of circles.

Wanted result:

[image: wanted result]

My result:

[image: my result]

```
import turtle


def centered_circle(circle_radius, turtle):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(circle_radius)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(circle_radius)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.backward(circle_radius)
    turtle.penup()

def circles(circle_radius, turtle):
    centered_circle(circle_radius, turtle)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
    centered_circle(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle)
    turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
    centered_circle(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle)
    turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
    centered_circle(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle)
    turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)


# Here is the recursive function which my question is about

def recursive_circles(circle_radius, turtle):
    if circle_radius > 2:
        centered_circle(circle_radius, turtle)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        centered_circle(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle)
        recursive_circles(circle_radius - 25, turtle) #Recursive call 
        turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        centered_circle(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle)
        recursive_circles(circle_radius - 25, turtle) #Recursive call 
        turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        centered_circle(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle)
        recursive_circles(circle_radius - 25, turtle) #Recursive call 
        turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)



def main():
 
    # Set up the turtle and window
    recursive_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    recursive_turtle.speed(0)
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    recursive_turtle.penup()
    recursive_turtle.left(90)
    recursive_turtle.backward(100)


    # Draw the circles
    recursive_turtle.penup()
    recursive_turtle.goto(0, 100)
    recursive_turtle.setheading(90)
    recursive_circles(50, recursive_turtle)

    myWin.exitonclick()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The if statement has to be > 2, and no for loop or while

Comment: But you call: `recursive_circles(50, recursive_turtle)`, so the further recursive calls subtract `25` off that `50`, then the next level will subtract `25` off that resulting in `0` which is not `>2`, so the recursion ends.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking some parts of your program.

The `recursive_circles()` function only needs to draw its own circle, move to other relative positions and call `recursive_circles()` to draw all the other circles down from there,

Also the radius should be halved in size on forward calls.

```py
import turtle

def centered_circle(circle_radius, turtle):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(circle_radius)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(circle_radius)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.backward(circle_radius)
    turtle.penup()

def recursive_circles(circle_radius, turtle):
    if circle_radius > 2:
        centered_circle(circle_radius, turtle)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        recursive_circles(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle) #Recursive call
        
        turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        recursive_circles(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle) #Recursive call 

        turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(circle_radius * 1.5)
        recursive_circles(circle_radius * 0.5, turtle) #Recursive call 
        turtle.backward(circle_radius * 1.5)


def main():
    # Set up the turtle and window
    recursive_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    recursive_turtle.speed(0)
    recursive_turtle.hideturtle()
    myWin = turtle.Screen()

    # Draw the circles
    recursive_turtle.penup()
    recursive_turtle.goto(0, 100)
    recursive_turtle.setheading(90)
    recursive_circles(50, recursive_turtle)

    myWin.exitonclick()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```